# Java regex _ text between tags?

Tags: java, regex

How I can get `String`from between tags, I have :

```
<span style="color: rgb(51, 102, 255);"><br>AAA </span>
<span style="color: rgb(51, 102, 255);">BBB : </span>
<span style="color: rgb(51, 102, 255);"><br>CCC : </span>
```

I need to :

```
<br>AAA
BBB :
<br>CCC
```

I wrote this but don't work :

```
   String _comment = "*my html*"

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<span style=\"color: rgb(51, 102, 255);\">(.+?)</span>", Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
        for (Matcher m = p.matcher(_comment);  m.find(); ) {
            String tag = m.group(1);
        }
```

Comment: Better use a specialized XML/HTML parser

Comment: There should be an automatic warning on SO when regex and html are part of a question :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your regex is that you did not escape `(` and `)`. I guess you need

```
<span style=\"color: rgb\\(51, 102, 255\\);\">(.+?)</span>
```

Double slash is to ensure one slash goes to the `compile` function.

But in fact, you should not use a regex to parse HTML at all. Use a specialized HTML parser and work with the DOM tree.